# Mercurial merge with subrepo throw error about .hgsubstate

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, branching-and-merging

I am trying to merge my local with the changes I pulled and I get this error:

```
% hg merge --verbose --tool=internal:fail 68
resolving manifests
'.hgsubstate'
[command returned code 255 Wed Apr 10 09:10:59 2013]
```

I am using TortoiseHg and the subrep doesn't show any uncommited changes.

This error msg is not very helpful in helping me figure out what to fix and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like [bug 3855](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3855) which was fixed in [hg 2.5.4](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive#Mercurial_2.5.4_.282013-04-04.29). There doesn't appear to have been a TortoiseHG release which includes this version yet, but you could perhaps ask on the thg mailing list if they are planning on putting out a new release. Until then you'll either have to downgrade to an older version of thg, or download the command-line-only version from [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download).